# Get full address details based on current location's latitude and longitude in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I have used the **location plugin** in the **flutter**, I can get the `latitude` and `longitude` only. How to get the full address details. Codes on below.

```
Future<Map<String, double>> _getLocation() async {
//var currentLocation = <String, double>{};
Map<String,double> currentLocation;
try {
  currentLocation = await location.getLocation();
} catch (e) {
  currentLocation = null;
}
setState(() {
  userLocation = currentLocation;
});
return currentLocation;



}
```

Comment: How can we get longitude and latitude?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Using [Geocoder](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/geocoder) plugin you can get address from the latitiude and longitude

```
 import 'package:location/location.dart';
 import 'package:geocoder/geocoder.dart';
 import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

getUserLocation() async {//call this async method from whereever you need
    
      LocationData myLocation;
      String error;
      Location location = new Location();
      try {
        myLocation = await location.getLocation();
      } on PlatformException catch (e) {
        if (e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED') {
          error = 'please grant permission';
          print(error);
        }
        if (e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED_NEVER_ASK') {
          error = 'permission denied- please enable it from app settings';
          print(error);
        }
        myLocation = null;
      }
      currentLocation = myLocation;
      final coordinates = new Coordinates(
          myLocation.latitude, myLocation.longitude);
      var addresses = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(
          coordinates);
      var first = addresses.first;
      print(' ${first.locality}, ${first.adminArea},${first.subLocality}, ${first.subAdminArea},${first.addressLine}, ${first.featureName},${first.thoroughfare}, ${first.subThoroughfare}');
      return first;
    }
```

**EDIT**

Please use [Geocoding](https://pub.dev/packages/geocoding) instead of [Geocoder](https://pub.dev/packages/geocoder) as **Geocoding** is maintained by [baseflow.com](https://pub.dev/publishers/baseflow.com/packages) agency.

Comment: ```Looks like the tutorial was done using an older version of the location plugin, since v2.0.0 they changed the api to return structured data rather than a map.

https://github.com/Lyokone/flutterlocation/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

So you'd need to either change all your Map<String, double> types to LocationData or set your plugin version to ^1.4.0.```

Comment: Thanks, ill check them out

Comment: Is there any free service to use map address to lat-long, lat-long to address and place autocomplete provider? Kindly suggest. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have try your answer but `geocoder` plugin is not null safe, how to solve this problem

Comment: Geocoder now is deprecated. If you try to import this plugin using pubspec.yaml, you will get the following error. **_The plugin geocoder uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs._**

Comment: I dont want a try catch in my release build, yet a user can still give the wrong untraceable address. What to do about this?

Comment: Is geocoding supported by flutter web application

Comment: What is the limitation of using this GeoCoding APIs ? Like number of request per second.

Answer (score 13):

This is the most simple way to get address from current position or any Latitude and Longitude using Google API.

### **You have to generate Goole Map API Key from Goole Console [Login Required]**
[Generate API Key From Here](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/maps-android-backend.googleapis.com?id=01d8f5af-dc9a-4b12-af6f-37029d8e3e71&project=verdant-medium-306417&supportedpurview=project)

```
  getAddressFromLatLng(context, double lat, double lng) async {
    String _host = 'https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json';
    final url = '$_host?key=$mapApiKey&language=en&latlng=$lat,$lng';
    if(lat != null && lng != null){
      var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
      if(response.statusCode == 200) {
        Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);
        String _formattedAddress = data["results"][0]["formatted_address"];
        print("response ==== $_formattedAddress");
        return _formattedAddress;
      } else return null;
    } else return null;
  }
```

Comment: is there any way to get split address like postcode street state etc?

Answer (score 12):

in pubspec.yaml

```
geolocator: '^5.1.1'
  geocoder: ^0.2.1
```

Import this packages

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:geocoder/geocoder.dart';


_getLocation() async
      {
        Position position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
        debugPrint('location: ${position.latitude}');
        final coordinates = new Coordinates(position.latitude, position.longitude);
        var addresses = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates);
        var first = addresses.first;
        print("${first.featureName} : ${first.addressLine}");
      }
```

Comment: Geocoder now is deprecated.

Answer (score 6):

Best approach in 2022.

GeoCoder is deprecated and will be removed in the future.
So, use GeoCode and use the below method to fetch the address.

```
import 'package:geocode/geocode.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

Future<Address> _determinePosition() async {
    bool serviceEnabled;
    LocationPermission permission;
    // Test if location services are enabled.
    serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      // Location services are not enabled don't continue
      // accessing the position and request users of the
      // App to enable the location services.
      return Future.error('Location services are disabled.');
    }

    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        // Permissions are denied, next time you could try
        // requesting permissions again (this is also where
        // Android's shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
        // returned true. According to Android guidelines
        // your App should show an explanatory UI now.
        return Future.error('Location permissions are denied');
      }
    }

    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      // Permissions are denied forever, handle appropriately.
      return Future.error(
          'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.');
    }

    // When we reach here, permissions are granted and we can
    // continue accessing the position of the device.
    final currentLocation = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
    final currentAddress = await GeoCode().reverseGeocoding(
        latitude: currentLocation.latitude,
        longitude: currentLocation.longitude);
    return currentAddress;
  }
```

Comment: Tried this but modified it in such a way that I do not have to acquire the current location of the user. Instead, `determinePosition()` accepts a `GeoPoint` input which contains a latitude and longitude component. It works at the start but when I try to move my camera (which also alters the GeoPoint passed), I start to get `null` values. Could this be due to the fact that GeoCode is limiting query to the application? Here's my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75774109/geocode-responds-very-slow-even-in-camera-idle-querries-in-android-flutter-googl

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use a "reverse geocoding" service, such as Google's API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start.  There are others out there as well... just google for "geocoding".

Update: apparently there's a local API as well.  See: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/geocoder

Comment: Is there any free service to use map address to lat-long, lat-long to address and place autocomplete provider? Kindly suggest. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It would be very unlikely, because there would be no monetization mechanism, so it would have to be done as an act of charity.

Answer (score 3):

i had done it recently You need GeoCoding Plugin then import this file

```
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';
```

After that, we have to create method.

```
getUserLocation(){
 List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
        currentPostion.latitude, currentPostion.longitude);
    Placemark place = placemarks[0];
   print(place)
}
```

You can access all property like name,locality using place object like place.name

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geocoder/geocoder.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

_getLocation() async {
GeolocationStatus geolocationStatus = await 
Geolocator().checkGeolocationPermissionStatus();

Position position = await Geolocator()
    .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
debugPrint('location: ${position.latitude}');


final coordinates = new Coordinates(position.latitude, position.longitude);
debugPrint('coordinates is: $coordinates');

var addresses =
    await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates);
var first = addresses.first;
// print number of retured addresses 
debugPrint('${addresses.length}');
// print the best address
debugPrint("${first.featureName} : ${first.addressLine}");
//print other address names
debugPrint(Country:${first.countryName} AdminArea:${first.adminArea} SubAdminArea:${first.subAdminArea}");
// print more address names
debugPrint(Locality:${first.locality}: Sublocality:${first.subLocality}");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since geocoder plugin as suggested in the above answers is obsolete, please use geolocator and geocoding plugins

```
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';


_getLocation() async
{
  Position position = await 
  Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: 
    LocationAccuracy.high);
  debugPrint('location: ${position.latitude}');
  List<Placemark> addresses = await 
  placemarkFromCoordinates(position.latitude,position.longitude);

  var first = addresses.first;
  print("${first.name} : ${first..administrativeArea}");
}
```

find geocoding pub link [geocoding flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/geocoding)

Answer (score 1):

you can use [geocoding.dart](https://pub.dev/packages/geocoding) package it has null safety and works perfectly fine

```
 determinePosition() async {
double latitude = 123.123;
double longitude = 123.123;
List<Placemark> list = await placemarkFromCoordinates(latitude, longitude);
print(list[0]);
return list[0];
```

}