# Convert LatLng data to String address location, Google maps

Tags: flutter, google-maps, geocoding, latitude-longitude

I am having trouble to convert the LatLng location of a marker from google maps to a address string on my flutter app. I have the LatLng data showing on a on my app when running, which get its data from the firebase backend latlng. But I cannot find a way on how to convert this into a address. I tried using geolocator and geocoding but could not find a way.

Here is my code for the latlng location output:

```
Align(
  alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0.0, 0.0),
  child: AutoSizeText(
           widget.location!.location!
             .toString()
             .maybeHandleOverflow(maxChars: 20),
  textAlign: TextAlign.start,
  style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
            .subtitle1
            .override(
              fontFamily: 'Poppins',
              fontSize: 18.0,
             ),
 ),
),
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeDgS.jpg)
Hope anyone can give me some tips on how to solve this, thanks.

I tried using geocoding, with this code:

```
widget.location!.latitude!, widget.location!.longitude!);
```

But received an error for this line of code the latitude and longitude isn't defined in the MapRecord

Comment: Use this package https://pub.dev/packages/geocoder

Comment: I did use it, still had the issue

Comment: Go through this once, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54761683/get-full-address-details-based-on-current-locations-latitude-and-longitude-in-f

Answer (score -1):

Please you can integrate this api. So please try it. This api free and open source.

Just pass your latlang and get data according to your latlang.

https://www.universal-tutorial.com/rest-apis/free-rest-api-for-country-state-city

**All credit by**: [www.universal-tutorial.com](http://www.universal-tutorial.com)

This is **100% work** for me so if any query so please reply.

Thank you for reading my answer.

Comment: I'd be worried about anything that returns `Byram` when asked for a list of the United States.

Comment: That API returns "Byram" as one of the states of the United States when asked for a list.  Byram is not a valid state name!